# Filter for first unique instance a column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How can I filter for unique values in a particular column (disregarding the values in the other columns for that row, and so the first instance of a new value would be fine)?

So, for example:

```
    1   2   3
A   10  a   a2
B   10  g   a3
C   20  h   a3
D   20  k   a3
E   20  l   b4
F   40  m   n6
G   40  q   q2
```

I would want my filter to show just rows A, C, and F.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to the data tab and click on 'Advanced' under 'Sort & Filter';
2. In the pop up, put the list range as the first column (header included) and check the 'Unique records only' checkbox.
3. Click OK and that should be it.

Comment: But how do we get the other rows? I just get 10;20;40...

Comment: In Excel 2016, there's no "Advanced" under Sort & Filter.

Comment: @jeancallisti I just looked for a picture of the data tab of excel 2016 (I have excel 365 on my machine, so I cannot directly confirm), but when I found one, the feature I mentioned is there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKhgb.png

Answer (score 6):

Add an extra column. Use the formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)` for that column, and copy it to the end

Filter on that column where the value is 1

Comment: In Excel 2016, this is not recognized as a valid formula. the final part (i.e. the final A1) triggers a "there's a problem with this formula"

Comment: @jeancallisti, if your local uses a semi colon to separate parameters then `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1;A1)` would be the correct form. You also cannot paste this into cell A1 as it will create a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, none of the suggested methods above were working (advanced filtering, remove duplicates, etc.)

Instead, I sorted Column 1 alphabetically then used a formula: =IF(A1=A0 (essentially one cell above),A1+1,1)

In layman: If cell A1 equals the column above, add 1. If it doesn't, set the cell equal to 1. Essentially if it isn't the first unique item in it's set, its 1. Therefore anything with a value of 1 is always unique.

Once you have it counting the number of items in a set, filter to 1. Those are your unique values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).